# SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE: A signer with SubjectDN using kubernetes and postman

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate

I'm having this error in my pod and I have done 2 days of research to try to fix the error but i still can't figure out what's wrong.

> CWPKI0823E: SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN [CN=cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud] was sent from the host [cloud.xxxx.container:443].  The signer might need to be added to local trust store [/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/keycopy.jks], located in SSL configuration alias [defaultSSLSettings].  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: [unable to find valid certification path to requested target].

1. I added a selfsigned certficate on the keycopy.jks which i created from my local machine. but i'm getting the same error.
2. tried to turn off the "enable ssl verification" to off and same error
3. and to add info, i have added the certificate i create in my postman in SETTINGS > CERTIFICATION > ADD CERTIFICATE.
4. i tried extracting a certificate from the keycopy.jks files itself and add it on my postmand request and still i'm having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Im no expert but have worked with SSL/TLS recently and found typically the SSL handshake failure occurs in the way you are experiencing when the common name (CN) does not match the hostname.

1. you created a cert for some CN domain - e.g. `example.com`
2. you then try to access the service using this SSL cert via `localhost:8080`
3. the cert returned from the server was for `example.com` not `localhost`.. handshake fails and no connection is established

Since you state you're getting a cert where the hostname/CN specified  is `CN=cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud` but the logs show a different domain `cloud.xxxx.container`, the connection fails - you're browser/ssl handshaker is trying to verify the host is who they say they are and getting a false result - so failing correctly.

If you are able to replace the cert to have `CN=cloud.xxxx.container` you will likely succeed in forming a connection.

Not sure if the following will work but it's quick/easy to test (and worked for my `example.com` vs. `localhost` example above, in the past, so I'll mention it, even though it may not work as expected (for testing purposes):

Create an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud   cloud.xxxx.container
```

This should result in your browser redirecting requests for `cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud` (for which the SSL cert will work) to `cloud.xxxx.container` without changing the url in the browser. This may enable the SSL handshake to succeed. Give it a go, let us know if it works.

Comment: thank you for info @Rob Evans. I'll try this one and update.

Comment: got stuck on different issue,.. i can work on this answer this week.. will keep you posted.

Comment: sounds familiar X'D

Comment: hi @Rob Evans, thank you for help and for waiting.. I have added a .cer file in my keycopy.jks in our server "kubernetes pod"  I have used "CN=cloud.xxxx.container" in creating the certificate. .. i have also tried editing my /etc/host/ but i'm still receiving the same error error... it's so weird,  does it make a difference if the .jks file is in the pod??

Answer (score 0):

my colleague was able to solve the issue... the issue was in the server.xml, he modified server.xml file,  changed keyStore id from "defaultTrustStore" to "defaultKeyStore" .

also found this as reference:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/core?topic=liberty-ssl-defaults-in

stated "Keystore: In the default configuration, the defaultKeyStore is used as both the key and truststore"